# Windows Forms Button codes

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am trying to create/code for a search button in C# Forms.

This what I have so far:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lstCustomerDB.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string item = lstCustomerDB.Items[i].ToString();
        if (item.Contains(txtSearch.Text)) 
        {
            index = 1;
        }
    }
    lstCustomerDB.Items.Clear();

    if (index < 0)
    {
      `enter code here`  MessageBox.Show("Item not found.");
        txtSearch.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        lstCustomerDB.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Any help would be grateful for! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry forget to mention it also has to be validated and indexed. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
private void Search()
{
    //Grab the first item that matches (or null if not found)
    var firstMatch = lstCustomerDB.Items.Cast<string>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(txtSearch.Text));
    if (firstMatch != null)
    {
        lstCustomerDB.SelectedItem = firstMatch;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item not found.");
        txtSearch.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Modifying your code:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < lstCustomerDB.Items.Count; i++)
{
     string item = lstCustomerDB.Items[i].ToString();
     if (item.Contains(txtSearch.Text)) 
     {
         index = i;
         lstCustomerDB.SelectedIndex = index;
         break;
     }
}
if (index < 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Item not found.");
     txtSearch.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work once i add in the break.  But Thanks!